# Is there a keystroke combination like "WIN + Left-arrow" In Linux (openSUSE)?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keystroke combination like "WIN + Left-arrow" in Linux (openSUSE), which moves the active window to the right half of the current screen?

**Edit:**

The solution I found is:

1. Download "ctrlwm" from http://gtk-apps.org/content/show.php/ctrlwm?content=114565
2. Open the Control Panel of openSUSE, click on "Regional and Accessiblity", and click on "Keyboard shortcuts"
3. Add a shortcut with "meta + left" and point it to ctrlwm with the additional parameters `-z -u`

Comment: glad you figured it out mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an older question, so the solution I'm about to describe may not have been available back when this was first asked.

In OpenSUSE 12.3 (KDE), one can do the following:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type "systemsettings" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click on "Shortcuts and Gestures", select "Global Keyboard Shortcuts" from the pane at the left, and select "KWin" (the KDE default window manager) from the "KDE component" drop-down menu.
- Scroll down until you see in the "Action" column the actions "Quick Tile Window to the Left [/Right]"

These are the actions you want to map to the <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> keybindings -- just click on the actions, input the mappings, and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the window manager you're using, not your flavor of Linux. I'm assuming you use KDE on OpenSuse.

If you're running compiz, I understand it's quite easy: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1325473

Also, check this out: http://gtk-apps.org/content/show.php/ctrlwm?content=114565

Comment: I see. Well, indeed I am using KDE. I gave "ctrlwm" a try, though did not yet fully understand of how to use it properly. The keyword of my problem seems to be "tiling window manager" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#List_of_tiling_window_managers_for_X)